# Exclude chars from range in ANTLR lexer

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I am trying to define a token fragment in ANTLR. It is a sequence of characters from the Unicode range `!` to `~` but it cannot contain whitespace or any delimiters.

```
fragment RegularCharRange : '\u0021'..'\u007e' ;

fragment WhitespaceChar : [\u0000\t\n\f\r ] ;

fragment DelimiterChar : [()<>[\]{}/%] ;
```

The following is invalid ANTLR syntax, but it expresses what I'm trying to do.

```
fragment RegularChar :  RegularCharRange & ~WhitespaceChar & ~DelimiterChar ;
```

Once defined the fragment will be used like this:

```
Name : '/' RegularChar* ;
```

How can I construct the `RegularChar` rule to preserve the readability of my tiny lexer grammar, without resorting to its definition as a list of unicode ranges (which would also force me to learn the order of each of my whitespace and delimiter characters so that they fit into the correct locations within the aforementioned range)?

**EDIT**:
I am aware that I can achieve the correct behaviour like this, but I'm looking to construct my lexer rule from re-usable fragments:

```
fragment RegularChar
    :  ~( '\u0000'..'\u0020' | '\u007f'..'\uffff' | [\u0000\t\n\f\r ] | [()<>[\]{}/%] )
    ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is unfortunately no shortcut here. You either define the ranges separately, or negate as you did in your **EDIT**.

Comment: Thank you, Bart :(

Comment: No problemo. You could submit a feature request for such a thing though, it would be nice: https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/issues

Comment: My first ever feature request: https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/issues/2246